# Area under curve vs. over curve

Tags: calculus, integration

On the topic of integrals, why would integrating this figure from $$\int_{a}^{b}\textbf{F}(x,y)ds$$ give the area under the curve and not the area over the curve? Would simply integrating $\int_{b}^{a}$ give the area over the curve?

[image]

Comment: Can you see that integration gives the area under the curve in two dimensions?

Comment: As you wrote it, it's a line integral so it would be the area over the curve with $x$ fixed at $0$. A visual is a curtain over the curve with the height being the value of $F(0,y)$.

The shaded region is $\int_0^2 F(0,y) dy$.